# I'm not have shortcut about Selection to Cursor

Tags: shortcut

I have blender v2.79. But i don't have shortcut "Selection to Cursor (shift+ctrl+Y)". Have anyone know how to Assign a shortcut?
https://youtu.be/W5Qp2pUMeQE?t=4m56s

[image]

Comment: It is `Shift + Ctrl+ S`, not Y

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Nope, that's *Save As*.

Comment: Ah damn, you are right, meant `Shift + S`

Comment: There isn't any shortcut for that command specifically in default Blender. You can create one by just Right clicking on menu item and choosing Add Shortcut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a custom shortcut defined in the blender version he is using.

You can do this by opening the menu, right clicking on the item, hovering over the box and putting in a shortcut.

[image]